# Calling a Vue 3 parent method based on the string payload of a child component's emitted event

Tags: javascript, vue.js, frontend, vuejs3

In Vue3 I want to call a function based on the value of the payload of an event, I'd like to do this in the template.

I have a parent component 'Parent' and child 'ButtonBar' here is what the code in 'ButtonBar' looks like:

```
  <ButtonBarButton
    v-if="button.label != null"
    @click="$emit('buttonClick', button.clickFunction)" 
    :label="button.label"
    :position="button.position"
    :icon="button.icon"
    :condition="button.condition"
    :class="buttonClass(button.position)"
  />
```

where button.clickFunction is String (i.e. 'closeStep', 'nextStep', or 'previousStep'). These values correspond to the names of functions I want to call in parent.

Here is 'Parent' where I'm trying catch that event and then call a function corresponding to button.clickFunction.

```
<ButtonBar
  :buttons = this.buttons 
  v-on:buttonClick="$event"
```

/>

In this case, it seems like nothing happens after 'Parent' catches the buttonClick event.

I've also tried v-on:buttonClick="$event()" but I receive errors that state "$event is not a function".

In short, I want to be able to access the value of $event and call the function which is named the same as that data.

Answer (score 0):

You would basically have to go back to Options API which could dynamically call methods using their name like `this[methodName]()`

With Composition API no longer having access to `this`, a minimal workaround solution would involve wrapping your methods in an object that makes them callable in a similar way to Options API.

```js
const dynamicMethods = {
  nextStep: () => {
    console.log('next step')
  },
  
  closeStep: () => {
    console.log('close step')
  },
  
  prevStep: () => {
    console.log('prev step')
  }
}
```

```html
<ButtonBar @buttonClick="dynamicMethods[$event]()" />
```

Say you still want to call `nextStep()` elsewhere in your code and not have to always call it like `dynamicMethods.nextStep()`, you can still do that by destructuring `dynamicMethods` on a different line:

```js
const { nextStep, closeStep, prevStep } = dynamicMethods
```

Now your methods are dynamically callable from the template with minimal changes to your script code.

[Vue Playground example](https://play.vuejs.org/#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)